# How do create a scale for a second axis without unnecessary (or redundant) plotting?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, axes

I have a plot in which I have already plotted all my data and a "twined" axis, on which I'd like to use another scale, in this case dates. I also have a list of all the dates corresponding to each element of my data, and want to add an a scale for the dates to the twined axis.

For example, I have

```
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
```

and lists `x_temporal_data`, `y_day_offsets`, `y_dates`, all of the same length, and have already plotted the relationship between the first two with

```
ax1.plot(x_temporal_data, y_day_offsets)
```

and I *just want to have a scale* on `ax2` for the dates in `y_dates`, since `y_day_offsets` and `y_dates` are "synonyms" for the same time information.

Is there a way to do this without "plotting" something I don't need to display (since all my data is already plotted). For example, I can get the dates to appear perfectly on `ax2` with

```
ax2.plot(len(y_dates)*[some_random_out_of_xrange_value], y_dates)
```

but that seems like a hack: plotting nothing to "calibrate" the second axis.

Is there a better, more idiomatic way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the scale on the second y-axis to your liking with:

```
ax2.set_ylim([min(y_dates), max(y_dates)])
```

Comment: Duh! My mistake. I'd tried this, but with `[y_dates[0], y_dates[-1]]` and though `y_dates` is in order, the type (an `numpy.array` of `datetime`) was causing the results to behave unexpectedly.